# Can you test a contract function transaction by calling it instead

Tags: metamask, contract-invocation, contract-debugging

I am trying to test my deployed smart contract functions without having to go through the transaction and pay gas fees.
I saw that Metamask can detect if a smart contract function is going to fail before you actually send the transaction, and I would like to be able to do that too for my case.

my theory is that Metamask would send a call method (not a transaction) to the same function you are calling and see if it reverts. IS that a reliable way of testing contract methods? does it use gas?

Comment: "I am trying to test my deployed smart contract functions without having to go through the transaction and pay gas fees" why is that? that's what testnets are for. And i believe what metamask actually does is run the transaction locally as you would do on a hardhat local network.

Comment: @Foxxxey my project depends on a live data feed from the mainnet. the testnet wouldn't fit for this.

Answer (score 5):

Your theory is correct. MetaMask sends a static (local) call to the contract. The call is the same as a real transaction, except 1) its state changes are not persisted 2) it doesn't cost any gas, since it doesn't send a transaction to the blockchain 3) is executed against your local node's data only.

That way is not 100% accurate, but it's basically the best there is.

As far as I can tell, MetaMask uses this call to do two things: 1) detect whether the transaction would probably fail and warn user if it would 2) estimate gas requirements.

Comment: thanks, nice to know that. So If I am correct if I am connected to the mainnet via a light node, there is a chance that the test request metamask does may not return the true results. and changing to an archive node might give me the true results, right ?

Comment: Not really. If your node is synchronized, it should give the same result as any other synchronized node. Archive node helps only if you need to dig history.